# O que são provedores? Qual a diferença entre OLE DB e ODBC?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, odbc, oledb

Preciso fazer a leitura de arquivos `dbf`. Achei um tutorial para leitura do mesmo onde o autor utiliza estes dois provedores. No código só vi diferenças na string de conexão.

O que são esses provedores? Qual a diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## ADO.NET

A [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-architecture?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) diz bem o que é. Vou só resumir.

São componentes para dar acesso (leitura) a dados vindos de uma determinada fonte, provavelmente um banco de dados. Existem operações comuns que estes provedores devem fornecer. O ADO.NET os trata de forma abstrata e os provedores os implementa de forma concreta de acordo com as especificidades da fonte de dados.

A ideia é que o acesso à qualquer fonte de dados seja feita de forma transparente. Que pareça que tudo vem de algo comum, que não seja necessário entender o funcionamento específico da fonte. isto simplifica inclusive a troca de uma fonte por outra.

Estes provedores funcionam como se fossem os *drivers* ODBC e OleDB mas implementam uma forma mais adequada para o .NET.

Se você entende como o `dbf` funciona, talvez entenda o que sejam os RDD ([Replaceable Data Drivers](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbour_(compilador)#Suporte_a_banco_de_dados)). É basicamente a mesma coisa.

Alguns [provedores definidos pela Microsoft podem ser achados aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/data-providers?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Qualquer um pode definir seus próprios provedores. Há empresas especializadas nisto e alguns banco de dados do mercado fornecem provedores para o ADO.NET. [Exemplos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

## OleDB

Como se vê os próprios *drivers* [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) e [OleDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_DB) são provedores do ADO.Net.

O provedor OleDB apenas pode acessar fontes de dados que conseguem se comunicar com esta tecnologia. A própria Microsoft está abandonando seu suporte em alguns dos seus produtos.

## ODBC

O ODBC é uma forma mais universal de acesso a fontes de dados.

Ambos devem ser evitados porque é uma camada a mais, tem um custo de processamento extra, embora o OleDB evita um pouco isto. Provedores mais específicos para um banco de dados ou outra fonte sempre é mais vantajoso. A implementação deles são mais eficientes por conhecerem como acessar os dados da melhor forma. Usa-se provedores mais genéricos, como os dois exemplos citados, quando não existe um provedor mais específico.

As definições formais podem ser obtidas no *links* acima.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Há um provedor ado.net específico para dbf?

Comment: Que eu saiba não. E já procurei. Mas faz tempo.

Answer (score 12):

A diferença está nos recursos que cada um conta e os bancos de dados que o mesmo suporta.

O `ODBC` (Open Database Connectivity) é um padrão para acesso a sistemas gerenciadores de bancos de dados (SGBD). São drivers para inúmeros Bancos de dados, como SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL entre outros.

O `OLE DB` é uma API desenvolvida pela Microsoft que atua com uma interface que permite o acesso universal a diversas fontes de dados.

Eles possuem basicamente a mesma função, com a diferença do `OLE DB` acessar outras fontes de dados além de Banco de Dados Relacionais.

Apesar de vários Banco de Dados fornecerem suporte ao `OLE DB`, a própria Microsoft desencoraja seu uso a favor do `ODBC`, tanto que o `OLE DB` será [descontinuado a partir do SQL Server 2012](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlnativeclient/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access) e o mesmo será removido em futuras versões.

Answer (score 6):

> Provedor é algo que te ajuda, que fornece algo no caso uma conexão.
>
> OLE DB e ODBC são APIs que permitem o acesso a uma gama de fontes de dados.

- (ODBC), é um padrão internacional para manipular dados relacionais
  usando a sintaxe de consulta SQL em diferentes fontes de dados. ODBC
  tem a vantagem de ser um padrão internacional que permite manipular
  uma grande variedade de fontes de dados relacionais através de
  diversos Drivers de ODBC da Microsoft e terceiros de fornecedores. A
  principal desvantagem do ODBC é que é limitado a relacional, sintaxe
  SQL com base em dados.

  ```
                                         X
  ```
- OLE DB é a interface de baixo nível estratégico da Microsoft para
  dados em toda a organização. OLE DB é uma especificação aberta
  desenvolvida para proporcionar o sucesso do ODBC, fornecendo um
  padrão aberto para acessar todos os tipos de dados. OLE DB não impõe
  nenhuma limitação específica na sintaxe da consulta ou a estrutura
  dos dados expostos como ele pode ser recuperado em formato tabular.
  Um provedor de dados OLE DB é análogo a um Driver de ODBC, expondo
  uma fonte de dados para um OLE DB consumidor, como ADO. Uma variedade
  cada vez maior de dados provedores do OLE DB sendo disponibilizados
  por fornecedores de Microsoft e de terceiros. O primeiro provedor de
  dados OLE DB, provedor Microsoft OLE DB para Drivers ODBC, permite
  que você exponha a qualquer fonte de dados ODBC para um consumidor de
  OLE DB.

Comment: Já que você quer evoluir, vou te ajudar. Procure dar contexto à pergunta. Definições qualquer um pode achar na Wikipedia, ou pode procurar na Google. Precisamos de informações que acrescentem alguma coisa e principalmente que respondam a pergunta específica. Se for colocar um conteúdo externo (que pode ser copiado), cite a fonte sempre. Por outro lado não coloque **SÓ** links, especialmente se ele não é de uma fonte bem estável (ele pode desaparecer). Use o link como informação adicional, mas agregue conteúdo útil para o contexto da pergunta. Entenda a pergunta antes de responder. Olhe as Tags