# O que é ADO.NET para C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, ado.net

Estou começando a aprender sobre C# para aplicações Web, e queria saber o que é o ADO.NET e quais as vantagens de usar ele?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pode usar com qualquer linguagem compatível com o .NET. C# é a principal delas.

Tem [informações básicas na nossa *tag*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/ado.net/info). E a [página oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET).

Ele é o mecanismo básico para acesso a banco de dados utilizado pelo .NET. É vantajoso neste sentido. Não em comparação a outra coisa. Ele dá uma funcionalidade para a plataforma de desenvolvimento.

Ele é um *framework* com a infraestrutura básica para a comunicação com os mecanismos que gerenciam as bases de dados. Também possuem algumas facilidades para abstrair estes dados na aplicação. Mas estas funções são usadas cada vez menos e se faz uso dos chamados ORMs, como o [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ([Core](https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) e [oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)), [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/) ou os mais simples como o [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

Quando se usa um ORM, o ADO.NET se torna transparente ou desnecessário. Mas se quiser fazer tudo na mão e de forma mais simples, mais bruta, o ADO.NET é mais interessante. Nem sempre o que é "mais moderno" é a melhor solução para tudo.

Também é possível usar outros mecanismos como [OleDB](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22460/101) ou ODBC, ainda que eles estejam vinculados ao ADO.NET. São considerados obsoletos ou alternativa só quando o ADO.NET nativo de cada banco não pode ser usado por alguma razão.

As funções básicas dele são:

- abrir e sustentar um conexão
- montar e executar *queries*
- iterar sobre os dados obtidos

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).