# O que é map / reduce?

Tags: javascript

**Map / Reduce** é um conceito muito comum em `JavaScript` e muitas outras linguagens. O que ele significa e como funciona na prática?

Comment: Em JavaScript (e muitas outras linguages) a função `map` serve para aplicarmos individualmente determinada lógica sobre todos os elementos de um array, ou semelhante. `reduce`, por sua vez, para reduzirmos o array para um valor único. Porém não faço ideia de como isso é aplicado em banco de dados NoSQL. Se você puder incrementar sua pergunta e colocar exemplos verificáveis, talvez fique mais fácil visualizar sua dúvida.

Comment: Editei retirando a referência a banco de dados NoSQL, por não se aplicar a todos os casos, dada a variedade de implementação desse tipo de banco de dados.

Comment: Na minha humilde e simplista opinião, nada mais é que do que, dada uma coleção de informações/valores, agrupar seus elementos num conjunto menor através de um identificador comum

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### map(fn (`elemento`))

É utilizado para realizar uma transformação em todos os itens de um `array`. Similar ao `forEach()`, com a diferença que o callback de `map()` deve sempre retornar um valor - e este valor sempre será adicionado ao *array* de resultado.

```js
var arrOriginal = [1,2,3,4,5];

var arrFinal = arrOriginal.map(function (e) { return e * -1; });

console.log(arrFinal);
```

### reduce(fn (`valorCorrent`, `elemento`), `valorOriginal`)

É utilizado para transversar uma coleção, acumulando e re-injetando o resultado para cada interação:

```js
var vendedores = [
    { nome:'Adão', vendas:32 },
    { nome:'Bruno', vendas:23 },
    { nome:'Claudio', vendas:16 },
    { nome:'Dejair', vendas:7 },
    { nome:'Eduardo', vendas:4 },
    { nome:'Flavio', vendas:3 }
];

var totalVendas = vendedores.reduce(function(v, e) {
    return v + e.vendas;
}, 0);

console.log("Total de vendas: "+ totalVendas);
```

`reduce()` pode também ser utilizado para transformações de estrutura. O exemplo abaixo converte a lista de objetos para um único objeto com o par de propriedades nome/vendas dos elementos convertidos para propriedade/valor:

```js
var vendedores = [
    { nome:'Adão', vendas:32 },
    { nome:'Bruno', vendas:23 },
    { nome:'Claudio', vendas:16 },
    { nome:'Dejair', vendas:7 },
    { nome:'Eduardo', vendas:4 },
    { nome:'Flavio', vendas:3 }
];

var totalVendas = vendedores.reduce(function(v, e) {
    v[e.nome] = e.vendas;
    return v;
}, {});

console.log(totalVendas);
```

Answer (score 5):

Não tem nada a ver com JS ou NoSQL (estava na pergunta original). Claro, eles usam a técnica, mas associar a eles como se fosse algo fundamental não faz sentido. Foi difundido em linguagens funcionais onde a forma declarativa (dizer o que fazer e não o como fazer) se impõe.

Normalmente é um par de funções, uma que mapeia, ou seja, pega uma coleção de dados e processa cada item possivelmente filtrando alguma informação, calculando de alguma forma ou organizando na forma esperada, e outra que reduz a coleção a um resultado específico esperado baseando nos itens mapeados.

Em geral essas funções são "o como fazer", e "o que fazer" costuma ser definido por *lambdas*.

Claro que nada impede de usar a mesma técnica sem funções específicas.

É uma técnica que acaba se assemelhando com SQL que é uma linguagem declarativa.

Em JS a função [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) aplica uma função anônima recebendo um parâmetro com cada elemento que será enviado pela função. É basicamente um `for`, que inclusive é mais rápido que o `map()`. É só uma forma de abstrair o laço. A função `reduce()` usa uma função anônima que recebe dois parâmetros, um é o acumulador (que resultará a redução) e o outro é o item a ser acumulado (reduzido).

Algumas linguagens possuem funções mais especializadas para ajudar na performance. JS tem algumas, como a [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Até onde eu sei não há alguma técnica que possa otimizar o uso dessas funções em conjunto, como ocorre com [LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182176/101), por exemplo (que nem é tão boa quanto poderia ser). Então é só desperdício de recurso tendo que fazer pelo menos 2 laços com os mesmos dados.

A vantagem da técnica se dá quando há um *framework* muito eficiente e que consiga produzir melhores resultados do que escrever o laço na mão, o que é algo bem difícil de alcançar. No caso do JS é só conveniência (discutível). Eu não chamaria de MapReduce o que o JS faz, dado sua simplicidade.

Answer (score 2):

Exemplos em `C#` com `Linq`:

Map, utilizando o método `Select`:

```
var arrOriginal = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };  
var arrFinal = arrOriginal.Select(n => n * -1);
```

[Exemplo do Map no .Net Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MmU5g5)

Reduce, utilizando o `Sum`:

```
public class Vendedor
{
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public int Vendas {get;set;}
}

var vendedores = new List<Vendedor>() { 
            new Vendedor { Nome = "Adão", Vendas = 32 },
            new Vendedor { Nome = "Bruno", Vendas = 23 },
            new Vendedor { Nome = "Claudio", Vendas = 16 },
            new Vendedor { Nome = "Dejair", Vendas = 7 },
            new Vendedor { Nome = "Eduardo", Vendas = 4 },
            new Vendedor { Nome = "Flavio", Vendas = 3 }
        };

var totalVendas = vendedores.Sum(v => v.Vendas);
```

[Exemplo do Reduce no .Net Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mkTzAI)