# Como usar o fazer operação de redução (reduce) em objetos?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

No Javascript, quando preciso fazer uma operação de redução, uso o método `Array.reduce`.

Assim:

```js
var valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1000];

var resultado = valores.reduce(function (soma, atual) {
    return soma + atual;
})

console.log(resultado);
```

Porém, quando tento fazer com um `Array` de objetos, não dá muito certo:

```js
var valores = [{valor: 1}, {valor: 2}, {valor: 3}, {valor: 4}, {valor: 5}, {valor: 1000}];


var resultado = valores.reduce(function (soma, atual) {
        return soma.valor + atual.valor;
})

console.log(resultado);
```

Nesse caso, retorna `NaN`.

Mas eu gostaria de poder aplicar a operação de redução em um objeto em um determinado atributo específico.

Como fazer isso em Javascript?

Comment: pelo que parece os objetos que são lidos primeiros são o `valor1` e `valor2`, depois disso o primeiro valor `soma` começa a ser `undefined`. coloque um `console.log` no lugar do return dentro do `reduce` e você verá.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161754/101 Também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195126/101

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No teu primeiro exemplo não estás a passar o valor inicial da soma, deves fazer isso, é o segundo argumento do `.reduce(fn, valorInicial)`. Essa parte é igual nos dois exemplos.

A diferença para uma array de objetos é só passar a propriedade que tem o numero que precisas.

Ficaria assim:

```js
var valores = [{valor: 1}, {valor: 2}, {valor: 3}, {valor: 4}, {valor: 5}, {valor: 1000}];
var resultado = valores.reduce(function(soma, atual) {
  return soma + atual.valor;
}, 0)

console.log(resultado);
```

Em ES6 seria:

```js
var valores = [{valor: 1}, {valor: 2}, {valor: 3}, {valor: 4}, {valor: 5}, {valor: 1000}];
var resultado = valores.reduce(
    (soma, atual) => soma + atual.valor, 0
);

console.log(resultado);
```

Answer (score 5):

O primeiro parâmetro vai acumular a soma, uma opção para o seu caso é também indicar a inicialização:

```js
const valores = [{valor: 1}, {valor: 2}, {valor: 3}, {valor: 4}, {valor: 5}, {valor: 1000}];

const resultado = valores.reduce((a, b) => a + b.valor, 0);

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: +1 Eu tinha implementado da forma que eu respondi aqui no meu sistema, mas acabei usando essa aí :D

Answer (score 5):

Você esqueceu de passar o segundo parâmetro para a função reduce, que é o valor que será iniciado a operação, veja:

```
var valores = [{valor: 1}, {valor: 2}, {valor: 3}, {valor: 4}, {valor: 5}, {valor: 1000}];

var resultado = valores.reduce(function (soma, atual) {
    return soma + atual.valor;
}, 0) // Inicia o valor de soma com 0

console.log(resultado); // 1015
```

Answer (score 3):

É preciso, antes de mais nada, entender que na função `reduce` o retorno de cada execução/iteração será usado como primeiro parâmetro na próxima iteração.

No código da pergunta é retornado um número na primeira iteração e nas próximas está tentando acessar a propriedade `valor` deste número.

É possível retornar um novo objeto que contenha a propriedade valor e fazer com que isto funcione do jeito que você espera.

```js
var valores = [{valor: 1}, {valor: 2}, {valor: 3}, {valor: 4}, {valor: 5}, {valor: 1000}];

var resultado = valores.reduce(function (soma, atual) {
  return { valor: soma.valor + atual.valor };
})

console.log(resultado);
```

Você também pode definir um valor inicial para as somas

```js
var valores = [{valor: 1}, {valor: 2}, {valor: 3}, {valor: 4}, {valor: 5}, {valor: 1000}];
    
var resultado = valores.reduce((soma, obj) => soma + obj.valor, 0);

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Interessante, eu tinha resolvido isso de outra forma, mas essa aí foi sensacional.

Answer (score 2):

Vou dar a minha palinha também. Basta usar o `Object.keys` para listar as chaves do objeto.

```js
var valores = [{valor: 1}, {valor: 2}, {valor: 3}, {valor: 4}, {valor: 5}, {valor: 1000}];

var resultado = Object.keys(valores).reduce(function (soma, key) {
    return soma + valores[key].valor;
}, 0)

console.log(resultado);
```

No meu caso, só deu o resultado esperado quando adicionei o valor inicial, definido no segundo parâmetro de `reduce`, com o `0`.

Comment: Pode ser útil também, principalmente se o uso das chaves for mais complexo dentro da função, mas como tem uma etapa antes só fica [um pouco mais lento](https://jsperf.com/object-array-reduce) :p